# Coding a random answer generator in Java - answers appear in a JFrame

Tags: java, random, jpanel

Just joined to seek help with some code I'm writing. I'm writing a basic Java program to help teach my students. The program uses the random controller to chose a random response which I have working through a terminal.

I'm taking this code to the next step and adding windows. I want this program to open a window, and upon clicking a button, a dialog box appears with the chosen answer. I have the windows working, but I cannot get it to display the string containing the random response.

I've attached my code. I think my problem is with my final line of code within the actionPerformed section. Does .showMessageDialog only handle pre-defined text and not strings?

Comment: Shake is defined inside the if statement. Define it outside, or add the showMessageDialog inside the { }s

Comment: How did I not think of that already?! Thank you very much, it now works a charm.

Comment: @Notorious also, consider a [`switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) instead of lots of `else if` statements

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in http://cseducators.stackexchange.com (though since it's still in private beta, it's easiest to enter through here https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shake` variable is not in showMessageDialog scope.
Two possible workarounds:

- Define shake outside the if(event.getSource()...) scope.
- Move the showMessageDialog statement inside brackets.

Comment: Thanks. For learning I tested both and each workaround yielded the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of your shake string is out of scope. You define it inside the if but use it outside. Move the 'String shake=" " ' in front of your if.

Sorry. Just saw that fmbesteiro solved it first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you even compile this?

variable "shake" is out of scope here.

Comment: That was my problem. Compiling wouldn't work and I know that variable was the problem. One of fmbesteiro's suggestions fixed it up.